# Get last index of an array using Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an `Object` that I'm iterating over, that contains array values, here's an example (Note that my version has a lot more information than just `content`):

```
$scope.messages = { "1": [ 
    { "content": "Hello" },
    { "content": "How are you" },
    { "content": "This should be displayed" }
]};
```

Take this as a "messaging thread" type of scenario, where you would group the threads by a phone number (in this event, `1`) and then show the last received message (the last index of the array).

Here's what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
<div ng-repeat="(thread_id, message_data) in messages">
    Thread ID: {{thread_id}} <br>
    Last message: {{message_data[message_data.length - 1].content}}
</div>
```

The thread id shows, but the message data does not.

Hardcoding the value such as:

```
{{message_data[0].content}}
```

works as expected.

Before people start suggesting `$last` please note that `$last` only returns true or false, depending on if the `ng-repeat` iteration is on its last cycle. Considering I'm using a `(key, value)` pair, and in my case the array is the value. I need the array length of the value, which `value.length` does provide. In this event:

```
 {{ message_data.length }}
```

will print out the value of `3`. However using `message_data.length - 1` to obtain a value from the array does not work.

Comment: @Trushnar - The `$last` variable returns a boolean, it says so straight on the document page. I need to get the length of the array in the `(key, value)` structure. Where the array is the `value`.. `$last` only returns true or false if the current `ng-repeat` iteration is on the last index. (In this case, it's the index of threads, not the index of messages)

Comment: works perfectly here http://jsfiddle.net/0jatojvg/ you have some internal issue, or given information is not enough to see the issue

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze - Oh joyous, aren't those the best! I just got it to work due to a suggestion by a friend. Which was to change the code to `message_data[(message_data.length - 1)].content` and apparently the parenthesis solved the issue.

Comment: i am still curious because in fiddle it works without parenthesis. Must be a version difference thing

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your html

```
ng-init="$last ? getLastIndex($index) : ''"
```

**Js**

```
$scope.getLastIndex = function (index){
  $scope.lastIndex = index;
}
```

Then this should work fine

```
message_data[lastIndex].content
```

Answer (score 0):

While my exact scenario may not be present on all versions of AngularJS, I solved the issue by surrounding my math in parenthesis.

```
message_data[(message_data.length - 1)].content
```